# Allow string to be null or empty in joi and express-validation

Tags: node.js, validation, joi

I am using "joi": "10.0.6" and  "express-validation": "1.0.1" in my project to validate a JSON object which I will save in the DB.
One of the field is a string but it could be null or empty.
How can I allow my string to pass the validation in the cases it is empty or null?

I have already tried these cases:

```
dataId: Joi.string().allow(null).allow('').optional()
```

and

```
dataId: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.string(), Joi.allow(null))
```

but both them don't work.

Answer (score 95):

You could also specify this with a comma delimited list.

```
dataId: Joi.string().allow(null, '')
```

See [Joi documentation on allow(value)](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.1.2/API.md#anyallowvalue)

Comment: I try to do the same using Express-validator/validator.js, any idea how to check for null and validates this correctly?
https://github.com/chriso/validator.js
https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator

Comment: I haven't used that library before, but looks like you could do so with a custom validator.
 
https://github.com/express-validator/express-validator#customvalidator

Comment: Yea I though the same, however the docs says: "Returns: the current validation chain instance". But I can't return 'null', since Express validator says it can't return null :S.

Answer (score 31):

It's very simple, suppose the field is data then you could impose the validation as

```
data: Joi.string().allow('')
```

allowing empty string to pass,
for multiple string validation it could also be done as

```
data: Joi.string().allow('', null)
```

allowing both empty as well as null value for the data field to pass.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to allow the empty string *and treat it the same as undefined* (i.e., convert it to undefined), then use Joi's [`empty` method](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.4.0#anyemptyschema):

```
data: Joi.string().empty('')
```

Answer (score 5):

If you just specify it as

```
dataId: Joi.string()
```

it should be optional per default.

EDIT: Could not try it on my own currently. Here an alternative, if above does not work:

```
dataId: Joi.string().min(0).allow('').allow(null)
```

Answer (score 5):

`Joi.string().allow('').allow(null)` should have worked. I tested locally and it works fine.

Show your test cases and errors?

Answer (score 3):

If you need only null or empty string use this:

```
 dataId: Joi.string().valid(null, '')
```